# Cannot cut raster by extension or mask layer

Tags: qgis, raster, error

I'm using QGIS 3.16.2 Hannover on my laptop with Windows 10.

1. **Problem:** I'm trying to cut by layer the satellite raster picture (I've chosen from the former XYZ tiles, added it to the program (actually I do not remember the source of the map and I do not know how to know it)
   1.1) I cannot cut by a mask layer, cannot cut by frame drawing: I receive the same error: the following layers were not correctly generated

the log is this:

```
Versión de QGIS: 3.16.2-Hannover
Revisión del código de QGIS: f1660f9da5
Versión de Qt: 5.11.2
Versión de GDAL: 3.1.4
Versión de GEOS: 3.8.1-CAPI-1.13.3
Versión de PROJ: Rel. 6.3.2, May 1st, 2020
Procesando algoritmo...
Algoritmo 'Cortar ráster por extensión' comenzando…
Input parameters:
{ 'DATA_TYPE' : 0, 'EXTRA' : '', 'INPUT' : 'crs=EPSG:3857&format&tilePixelRatio=1&type=xyz&url=http://www.google.cn/maps/vt?lyrs%3Ds@189%26gl%3Dcn%26x%3D%7Bx%7D%26y%3D%7By%7D%26z%3D%7Bz%7D&zmax=18&zmin=0', 'NODATA' : None, 'OPTIONS' : '', 'OUTPUT' : 'TEMPORARY_OUTPUT', 'PROJWIN' : '15678296.625900000,17753432.005399998,-1306601.446600000,-84337.104100000 [EPSG:3857]' }

GDAL command:
gdal_translate -projwin 15678296.6259 -84337.1041 17753432.0054 -1306601.4466 -of GTiff "crs=EPSG:3857&format&tilePixelRatio=1&type=xyz&url=http://www.google.cn/maps/vt?lyrs%3Ds@189%26gl%3Dcn%26x%3D%7Bx%7D%26y%3D%7By%7D%26z%3D%7Bz%7D&zmax=18&zmin=0" C:/Users/pirra/AppData/Local/Temp/processing_Sdzjqd/60e0ec134bbc4aef8abc17116acb745a/OUTPUT.tif
GDAL command output:
ERROR 4: `crs=EPSG:3857&format&tilePixelRatio=1&type=xyz&url=http://www.google.cn/maps/vt?lyrs%3Ds@189%26gl%3Dcn%26x%3D%7Bx%7D%26y%3D%7By%7D%26z%3D%7Bz%7D&zmax=18&zmin=0' does not exist in the file system, and is not recognized as a supported dataset name.

Execution completed in 0.22 seconds
Results:
{'OUTPUT': 'C:/Users/pirra/AppData/Local/Temp/processing_Sdzjqd/60e0ec134bbc4aef8abc17116acb745a/OUTPUT.tif'}

Cargando las capas resultantes
Las siguientes capas no se generaron correctamente.
• C:/Users/pirra/AppData/Local/Temp/processing_Sdzjqd/60e0ec134bbc4aef8abc17116acb745a/OUTPUT.tif
Puede comprobar el «Panel de mensajes del registro» en la ventana principal de QGIS para encontrar más información sobre la ejecución del algoritmo.
```

I suppose is the problem with the raster

2)**other question:**

Is there no way to discover what is going wrong? I ALWAYS have the same text from the box code: the following layers were not correctly generated. This tells me nothing about my issues (frequent issues, I'm a beginner). Is not there some plugin for noobies? [image: the problem]

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE. As a new user, please take the [Tour], which emphasizes the importance of asking One question per Question. As soon as you start bulleting questions, you increase the chance of your question being closed as *unfocused*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

XYZ tiles are pictures of data not data, so as the error says they `do[es] not exist in the file system, and is not recognized as a supported dataset name.`

If you want to extract data then you need an actual raster layer as the input.

Comment: As a workaround, you can create a raster file from the visible extent by saving as image, disabling all other layers and using EPSG:3857 as project CRS. You can add that image to the canvas, assign EPSG:3857 to it and treat that layer like a normal raster.